# Bog content is not working when I put the google adsense code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger-dynamic-views, adsense-anchor-ads

I got problem that my blog content is not working when I put the adsense code block in dynamic generated html. The problem has gone after I moved the adsense code block and everything is working well.

I used following code, it worked on desktop version but not in mobile version view.

$(document).ready(function(){(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})})